# Text cell numbering

Tags: notebooks, formatting, cells, text

For input cells and output cells, there are automatic,natural numbering.

```
In[1] 2+2
Out[1] 4
```

I mean In`[1]` and Out`[1]`.

For text cell, there is no automatic numbering, and I do not know how to give it.

I make a text cell by
`mouse right click` - `insert new cell` - `text`.

Q1) Numbering possible for text cell ?
Q2) automatic numbering possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'labels' for input and output are generated upon evaluation by the kernel and are not notebook specific. I do not think that this is what OP is after with text cells (I might be wrong). I would assume the question is about notebook/cell specific `CellFrameLabels` like the ones used by `DisplayFormulaNumbered`. An alternative approach I will not discuss here would be to set `CellLabel` manually (this is done for `Input` and `Output` cells automatically by the kernel/frontend).

Regarding Q1: I am not sure how to archive this but it might be possible to set `CellFrameLabels` manually.

I have however an answer for Q2: one can archive this quite easily be replicating the the cell style of `DisplayFormulaNumbered`. Here is an example for a style definition `TextCellNumbered` inheriting from `Text` and using a counter similar to the one used by `DisplayFormulaNumbered`:

```
Cell[StyleData["TextCellNumbered", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
   MenuSortingValue->1401,
   CounterIncrements->"TextCellNumbered",
   CellFrameLabels->{{None,Cell[TextData[{"(",CounterBox["TextCellNumbered"],")"}],"TextCellNumber"]}, {None, None}}
]
```

If one places this into a style sheet or embedded notebook style definitions (The simplest way to do so is to use the menu "Format->Edit Stylesheet", then use "Customize Inherited Style" or "Add a New Style" to create a Cell in the style sheet and then mark the cell and use STR+SHIFT+E or the menu "Cell->Show Expression" to edit/paste the code given above directly into the cell expression. To apply the edited changes to the cell revert "Cell->Show Expression") one can use `TextCellNumbered` to get something like

[image: Numbered Text]

Some possible extensions and improvements could involve: assigning a `MenuCommandKey` to this style to insert it with a shortcut (ALT+Number) or to change the appearance/style of the label in `CellFrameLabels` with other brackets or to include the chapter number in the label with `CounterBox["Chapter"]` (and setting `CounterAssignments->{{"TextCellNumbered", 0}}` in the style for `Chapter`).

Comment: ((("Format->Edit Stylesheet", then use `Customize Inherited Style` or `Add a New Style`))) <- where is `Customize Inherited Style` or `Add a New Style`? My version is  v12.2